# Openning two javascript:OpenPopUpPage dialogs at the sametime

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, html, popup

I have added a script editor inside my team site, that contains two links to show pop-ups dialogs as follow:-

```
<li unselectable="on"><a href="javascript:OpenPopUpPage('/view/viewer_index.shtml?id=726',1000,1000);" unselectable="on">Camera1</a></li>

<li unselectable="on"><a href="javascript:OpenPopUpPage('/view/viewer_index.shtml?id=728',1000,1000);" unselectable="on">Camera2</a></li>
```

But currently If the user click on camera1 link , he cannot navigate to the camera2 link, as it seems that javascript:OpenPopUpPage  will block the SP site from navigation.

So my question is  how I can allow the user to open more than one JavaScript pop-ups at the same time ?

Comment: Do you want to open the windows as modal or normal windows?

Comment: As a modal/pop-up dialog .

Comment: Are you using the javascript SPModalDialog with options? Share OpenPopUpPage code and I will try to help you

Comment: thanks for you reply, i already provide the code for javascript:OpenPopUpPage. <li unselectable="on"><a href="javascript:OpenPopUpPage('/view/viewer_index.shtml?id=726',1000,1000);" unselectable="on">Camera1</a></li>

Comment: If you want to navigate to Camera 2 from the viewer_index.shtml that was opened by Camera 1 link is not possible because you are using Modal Dialogs. But you could put in your viewer_index.shtml some jquery code that gets de <li> nodes from parent or just passing the links in an ajax call as strings to build the DOM <li unselectable="on"><a href="javascript:OpenPopUpPage('/view/viewer_index.shtml?id=728',1000,1000);" unselectable="on">Camera2</a></li> in viewer_index.shtml

Comment: no i do not want to open camera2 from camera1 dialog. what i am planning is; a userA click on camera1 link, then the dialog open. then userA click on camera2 link then another dialog open. so that the user can see camera1 & camera 2 Dialogs (2 dialogs) at the same time

Comment: You cannot do that with modal dialogs. Is a requisite that must be opened in modal dialog? If not. you can do a javascript function using jquery dialog function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756283/jquery-dialog-to-open-another-page

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is that you are using Modal Dialogs. When using these, you must first complete the interaction with that modal window and then close it. More information here on the concept:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window

OOTB SharePoint uses modal windows and does not provide any other method in Javascript for overlaying other pages.

For your problem specifically, you can create an `iframe` and set the `src` attribute to the link that's needed to view.  Using CSS, you'll be able to position these iframes side by side as well as controlling the `z-index` so they will appear in front of the currently viewed page.